Continuous real-valued functions on linearly ordered spaces which have locally many points
Fix a cardinal $\kappa > 2^{\aleph_0}$. Let $(X, \leq)$ be a linearly ordered space such that for each $a < b$, $|(a, b)| \geq \kappa$. Can there exist a continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not locally constant?

Well, $X$ could be $\mathbb R$…

@EricWofsey Then we will have $|(a, b)| \not\geq \kappa$ I think, so the condition is not fulfilled

@Smiley1000 $\omega_1$ is not the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. If the continuum hypothesis is false, then $|\mathbb{R}|>\omega_1$. Perhaps you meant to assume $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$?

@AlexKruckman Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you

Yes, there are examples for arbitrarily large $\kappa$:
We need the following simple lemma (see also the update below):
Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $X$ compact and connected, $Y$ $T_1$. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is locally constant, then $f$ is constant.
PROOF. Since $f$ is locally constant, it is continuous.
Moreover, since $X$ is compact, $f(X)$ is finite, and it is also connected. Since $Y$ is $T_1$, $|f(X)| \le 1$. $_\square$
Now define $X = [0, 1]^\kappa$, ordered lexicographically.
It is easy to see that for $a, b \in X, a < b$, it is $|(a, b)| = 2^\kappa > \kappa$.
Moreover, $X$ is a complete lattice.
[This is certainly a well-known and old theorem. The only online reference I know of, is this one, Proposition 1.3]. 
Hence, $X$ with the order topology, is compact and connected.
Since $X$ is completely regular, there exists a continuous function
$f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $0, 1 \in f(X)$.
By the lemma, $f$ is not locally constant.
Update
Even this stronger version of the lemma holds:
Let X be a connected topological space, Y a set and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a locally constant map.
Then $f$ is constant.
[$ x \sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ defines an equivalence relation on $X$. Since $f$ is locally constant, the equivalence classes form an open, hence clopen, partition of $X$. By connectness of $X$, it consists of at most one element.]

Thanks for the answer and also for the reference
